# Are there integers a, b, c, d generating four right triangles with integer sides?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

To make this more precise, we are looking for four (ETA: distinct) positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, such that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, $\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$, $\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$, and $\sqrt{d^2+a^2}$ are all integers as well.

Equivalently, we seek a convex quadrilateral with integer sides, whose diagonals intersect at right angles at a point a (ETA: distinct) integer distance from all four vertices.

ETA: Answered in the affirmative below, by computer search.  Is there a more elegant, less brute-forcey way to such an answer?

Comment: I think you will get better results if you post a fresh question.  Don't forget this time to say that the numbers should be distinct.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I might.  But I mostly got the response I wanted, thanks to you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Computer search finds many examples; considering only those where all four numbers are distinct, we have for example:

$$\begin{align}
a & = 6375 \\ b& = 6512 \\ c & = 9984 \\d  & = 800
\end{align}$$

and 
$$\begin{align}
a & = 3472 \\ b& = 7296 \\ c & = 10400 \\d  & = 2175
\end{align}$$

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  (Sincerely.)  I did run a search, but didn't extend it far enough.  Also, I was curious whether there was better than a brute-force approach to the question.

Comment: My approach was a brute force search over all pythagorean triples. this is much faster than a search over all integers; It took a fraction of a second to run on my laptop.  If you're interested I'll be glad to explain in more detail.

Comment: No, I think I get the idea.  I was lazy previously.  But as you say, such a search, though not going through all quadruples, is still brute force.  Nothing wrong particularly about that, but I was hoping for something with a bit more analytical flavor to it.  Thanks for offering the answer so quickly!

Comment: @MJD:  Would you mind sharing your code?

Comment: @Tebbe https://github.com/mjdominus/perl-misc/blob/master/math/pt is the searcher, and https://github.com/mjdominus/perl-misc/blob/master/math/pttest is a checker that validates that the solutions printed by the first program are actually correct.

Comment: Let me know if you want further explanation.

Comment: I wrote this up [on my blog back in May](http://blog.plover.com/math/ounce-of-theory.html).

Answer (score 3):

$$ a=3, b=4, c=3, d=4........... $$

Comment: I'm wondering if there exist pairwise coprime integers satisfying the question.

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote it (and would not).  I've edited the question to eliminate that kind of answer.